# Rowchart with a custom reduce is not ordered correctly

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Having an issue with rowChart, where I'm trying to limit the number of rows displayed using cap() but the resulting chart is not ordering correctly; it seems to be ordering by the dimension rather than the group, regardless of whether cap() or rowsCap() is used. I have a custom reduce and the accessors behave as expected. I suspect there is a problem in the data because the code snippets below work as expected when i look only at the first character or two of the dimension but fail when I include the third character. Anyone seen this kind of behavior before and know how to resolve it?

```
            userDim[i] = facts.dimension(function(d) { return d[config[i].field]; });
            userGrp[i]  = userDim[i].group().reduce(reduceAddSAIDI(), reduceRemoveSAIDI(), reduceInitSAIDI);                

            var newMeasure = config[i].measure;

            chart[i] = dc.rowChart("#" +  config[i].tagID +"-chart");
            chart[i].dimension(userDim[i]);
            chart[i].group(userGrp[i]);
            chart[i].elasticX(true);
            chart[i].xAxis().ticks(2);
            chart[i].othersGrouper(false);
            //chart[i].rowsCap(25);
            chart[i].cap(25);
            chart[i].ordering(function(d){return -d.value[newMeasure];});
            chart[i].valueAccessor(function (d) { return -d.value[newMeasure];});
```

The binning function on the dimension which gives the expected result when the first two characters in the dimension field are used but seems to order incorrectly if the dimension array gets any larger:

```
    function binFeeder(inVal) {
    if (inVal != "")  {
        binVal = inVal.substring(0,2);
    } else {
        binVal = "NoData";
    }
    if (consoleDebug) console.log (inVal + " --> " + binVal); 
    return binVal;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the possible duplicate. There's some redundancy between dc.js ordering and crossfilter ordering [which will go away soon](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/934). Although it's slightly different symptoms as the linked question, sounds like it's probably the same root cause.

Comment: Perfect - adding the explicit ordering function worked. Thanks